# No such file or directory in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService()

Tags: 8, drush

I installed a fresh D8 (Drupal 8.6.15) site on my local dev and I am unable to use drush.

After I installed the site, I also did a `composer install`. My dev is set up on php 7.1 using AMMPS and drush 8.1.18.

> No such file or directory in
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService()
>   (line 79 of
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/commerce/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php).

Comment: `using AMMPS`... how many seconds does the `/admin/modules` page take to load?

Comment: Less than 1 second, why?

Comment: Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use drush 9.6 and updated that by `composer require drush/drush:"^9.6"`. Thanks drugan!

[image]